# Sharepoint Report center

Tags: feature

Is the Report Center option available for sub-site creation? I would like to utilize it for Director reporting and scorecards/dashboards

Answer (score 3):

The Report Center isn't tied down for RootWebOnly, but it's hidden so you have to create it using PowerShell:

> new-SPWeb -name "Report Center" -url http://sp2010/rc -Template "SPSREPORTCENTER#0"

Comment: so you mean that these option wont be available by default?

Comment: The "Report Center" site definition is hidden so it's not shown in the UI

Comment: Ok..thanks for the info..is there a reason why it is nt available by default?

Comment: I think MS is of the option that, the "Business Intelligence Center" is the replacement for "Report Center"